Chroot into current filesystem?
I need to test out setting up some development tools which has been a pain and messed up my system to have to reinstall for the 9th time. I discovered chroot, this will relief a lot of pain. But I am afraid that pulling a clean distribution with debootstrap from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ will still have differences with my own ubuntu noble arm64.
So I am looking for ways to install my own system on my home ~/chroot-ubuntu. Or is it simply copy and pasting? I want to figure it out without going for a 10th reinstall this time so asking for help this time.
Please, how to do this?
